# Changing height of <tr> in an html generated pdf not working

Tags: html, css, pdf-generation

So i'm trying to convert html page to pdf when i click a button, but my problem is that i've added a table to the pdf and for some reason I can't seem to change the height of the tr's, i want them to be bigger than they are in the pdf, this how they appear in the pdf:
[image]
but i want them to be like this:
[image]
i've used the same table to generate pdf and to generate a word document , in word its good but in pdf its like this, I don't know how to fix it, this is the code of the table i'm using:

```
<table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 650px">
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 217px">
<col style="width: 217px">
<col style="width: 217px">
<col style="width: 217px">
</colgroup>
<thead>
  <tr style="height:40px">
    <th class="tg-0pky"><h1 style="font-size: 14px">NOM ET PRENOM</h1></th>
    <th class="tg-0pky"><h1 style="font-size: 14px">ENTREPRISES</h1></th>
    <th class="tg-0pky"><h1 style="font-size: 14px">TELEPHONE</h1></th>
    <th class="tg-0pky"><h1 style="font-size: 14px">EMARGEMENT</h1></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr style="height:80px">
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

i generate this pdf  with mpdf function, i define a pdf like this `$mpdf=new \Mpdf\Mpdf();` then i create an empty variable like this `$data='';` then i put the table inside that variable and then i write to the pdf with `$mpdf->WriteHTML($data);` then print it `$mpdf->Output("maintien de l'offre 2020.pdf",'D');`

Comment: How are you creating the PDF? What code is being used is the inline style the only style beingnused?

Comment: with mpdf function, i define a pdf like this `$mpdf=new \Mpdf\Mpdf();` then i create an empty variable like this `$data=''; `then i put the table inside that variable and then i write to the pdf with `$mpdf->WriteHTML($data);`

Comment: I suggest adding that relevant coded to your question, you can edit it by pressing the edit button and then add any other relevant code. Try to give those that would help all the tools they can use to try and recreeate your issue and in turn solve it.

Comment: @dalelandry okay i will^^

Comment: Put a space character in the cells and set a large line-height or font-size.

Comment: @KevinBrown okay thank u i will try